# Can someone identify the error in this PHP function using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update a particular field in a mysql database. The field name is passed in a var, to a value (also passed in a var) where a specific field (memID) is equal to a particular value (also passed in a var). I'm using '?' placeholders.

```
function modFiltName($filtID,$newFN,$memID) { 
    include '../includes/setDBC.php'; //connect to dbc
    $stmt=$dbc->prepare('UPDATE mzfilters SET ? = ? WHERE memID=? ');
    $stmt->execute(array($filtID,$newFN,$memID));
    $dbc=null; // Close connection
}
```

It seems simple enough but I get errors no matter how I rearrange the code. The last error is typical of what I'm getting: ". . for the right syntax to use near '? = ? WHERE memID=?' " . .

Comment: you can't bind column names, only values.

Comment: You can't use placeholders for tablenames, column names or other identifiers.

Comment: Both of those should be answers, not comments, but it's closed now anyways.

Comment: OK, thanks for fast response. I did read in the PDO tutorial mentioned above that I can not parameterise table names. Reading more I now see that it applies to field names too. I can't imagine how I can do what I'm trying to here. I have 24 filters that I'd like the user to name as she wishes. Do I need to write 24 functions, each using a different filter ID? That seems intuitively wrong. I don't seem to be able to ask my question in a way that running a search yields an explanation for me.